# Query returns results on pgAdmin running on remote client but not directly through psql on db server

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin

When I query my database using a role in pgAdmin on a remote client, I get the results of the query. However if I run the same query directly on the db server with the same role , I don't see the query output. I see the table are present with the "\dt" command but I am not able to view the results of the queries on these tables. Is there some configuration that is needed to enable querying the db from the same host ?

Note:
Made edits to the question based on the comments.

Comment: You are probably connecting to a different server from within pgAdmin. Or you are using a different (Postgres) user

Comment: Can you specify "I cannot query the tables"?

Comment: Question needs to be a lot more specific to be useful.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: No the server and user are the same.Anyway, I found the solution to my problem

Answer (score 2):

Found the resolution to my issue. To check query results you need to terminate every query in psql with a semicolon `;`. If the semicolon is not used you don't see the query result when using the psql command line.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#R2-APP-PSQL-4)

> Entering SQL Commands
>   
>   ...
>   
>   At the prompt, the user can type in SQL commands. Ordinarily, input lines are sent to the server when a command-terminating semicolon is reached. An end of line does not terminate a command. Thus commands can be spread over several lines for clarity.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026/in-psql-why-do-some-commands-have-no-effect